# como cadastrar um novo usuario setando SESSION como um dos valores da query

Tags: php, mysql, crud

eu quero cadastrar um novo Usuário por um gerente e setando o id da empresa no bd, a maneira que fiz deu certo ao cadastrar outras tabelas mas nessa esta dando problema mas eu sei que o valor da session carrega pois fiz retornar os valores que estavam carregados nas variáveis, mas ele simplesmente não cadastra e não mostra nenhum erro...

```
-----------------controller ---------------------

<?php

    session_start();

require_once("../../model/usuarioModel/Usuario.php");
class ControllerCadastrarUser{

     private $cadastro;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->cadastro = new Usuario();
        $this->incluirUsuario();
    }

    private function incluirUsuario(){
        $this->cadastro->setNome_usuario($_POST['nome_usuario']);
        $this->cadastro->setTipo_usuario($_POST['tipo_usuario'] );
        $this->cadastro->setLogin($_POST['login'] );
        $this->cadastro->setSenha($_POST['senha'] );
        $this->cadastro->setId_empresa($_SESSION['empresa_id_empresa']);

        $result = $this->cadastro->incluirUsuario();
        if($result >= 1){
            echo "<script>alert('Registro incluído com sucesso!');document.location='../../view/empresa/cadastroEmpresa.php'</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Erro ao gravar registro!, verifique se email ou senha não estão errados!');history.back()</script>";
        }
    }
}
new ControllerCadastrarUser();



------------------- DAO  -------------

require_once("../../init.php");

class UsuarioDao {

    protected $mysqli;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexao();
    }

    private function conexao(){
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(BD_SERVIDOR, BD_USUARIO , BD_SENHA, BD_BANCO);
    }

    public function setUsuario($nome_usuario, $tipo_usuario, $login, $senha,$id_empresa){

        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (`nome_usuario`, `tipo_usuario`, `login`, `senha`, `empresa_id_empresa`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$nome_usuario,$tipo_usuario,$login,$senha,$id_empresa);
         if( $stmt->execute() == TRUE){
            return true ;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}


------------------------ CLASSE USUARIO ---------------

require_once("UsuarioDao.php");
class Usuario extends UsuarioDao {
    private $nome_usuario;    
    private $tipo_usuario; 
    private $login; 
    private $senha; 
    private $id_empresa;


    function getNome_usuario() {
        return $this->nome_usuario;
    }

    function getTipo_usuario() {
        return $this->tipo_usuario;
    }

    function getLogin() {
        return $this->login;
    }

    function getSenha() {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    function getId_empresa() {
        return $this->id_empresa;
    }

    function setNome_usuario($nome_usuario) {
        $this->nome_usuario = $nome_usuario;
    }

    function setTipo_usuario($tipo_usuario) {
        $this->tipo_usuario = $tipo_usuario;
    }

    function setLogin($login) {
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    function setSenha($senha) {
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }

    function setId_empresa($id_empresa) {
        $this->id_empresa = $id_empresa;
    }

    public function incluirUsuario(){
        return $this->setUsuario($this->getNome_usuario(),$this->getLogin(), $this->getId_empresa(), $this->getTipo_usuario(), $this->getSenha());
    }

}
```

O que devo fazer? Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas no seu INSERT é definido 5 colunas, e vc tenta passar 6 valores

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que parece, seu Insert que está com problema, pois você está passando 5 colunas e 6 valores, logo uma ficará sobrando.

Um bom método para testar se o seu código Sql está funcionando, é indo direto ao PhpMyAdmin e testar o código lá em sua tabela, pois dessa forma você consegue verificar melhor os erros apresentados, caso ocorra.

Após entrar no PhpMyAdmin, basta selecionar o banco de dados que está usando e depois ir na aba "Sql", lá você encontrará o campo para inserir seu código Sql. Basta substituir as variáveis por valores genéricos.

Ficaria assim:

```
INSERT INTO usuario (`nome_usuario`, `tipo_usuario`, `login`, `senha`, `empresa_id_empresa`) VALUES ('nomeTeste','tipoTeste','loginTeste','senhaTeste', 1)"
```

Obs: atente-se ao tipo de dado a ser inserido (varchar, int, float, etc)